# Apply CSS-Accordion to different buttons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code:

Javascript:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("button");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
.button{
    display:block;
    height:431px;
    width:100%;
    font-family: Futura, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif;
    color:black;
    font-size:80px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:transparent;
    border-style:none;
}

.button:hover{
    background: url('pcluj.jpg') ;
    background-size: cover;
}


.button1{
    display:block;
    height:431px;
    width:100%;
    font-family: Futura, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif;
    color:black;
    font-size:80px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:transparent;
    border-style:none;
}

.button1:hover, .button1.active{
    background: url('bucuresti.jpg') ;
    background-size: cover;
}

.button2{
    display:block;
    height:431px;
    width:100%;
    font-family: Futura, 'Trebuchet MS', Arial, sans-serif;
    color:black;
    font-size:80px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-color:transparent;
    border-style:none;

}

.button2.active, .button2:hover{
    background: url('sibiu.jpg') ;
    background-size: cover;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;


}

div.panel {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<center>
    <button class="button" id="button">CLUJ</button>
</center>

<div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<center>
    <button class="button1" id="button1" >BUCURESTI</button>
</center>

<div class="panel" id='panel'>
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>

<center>
    <button class="button2" id="button2">SIBIU</button>
</center>

<div class="panel">
    <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</div>
```

How can I make all the buttons act like an Accordion? I have different class names because each button has a different background image when I hover it.

This version of the code doesn't work for all the buttons, only for the first one. What is to be done?

Answer (score 0):

The variable acc is an array of buttons with class name "button". But you have class name as button for only one button element in your html code, so it works for the button CLUZ. As you have defined an id for each button try using id selectors (#button, #button1, #button2) in css instead of class selectors(.button,.button1,.button2) which helps you to have different background images. And have a same class name for all the buttons and use it in the below line

```
 var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("buttonName");
```